# How can I make a mapping of counters dynamic with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel with chevrons and pagination. When the carousel left chevron is clicked, a var `counter` is set to `--`, and when the right chevron is clicked, the `counter` is set to `++`.

I can't tie the pagination to the chevron animation as different events occur.

I have the below code for my pagination. When all events have completed, I set the following:

```
if (pagCount === 1) {
  counter = 0;
} else if (pagCount === 2) {
  counter = -1;
} else if (pagCount === 3) {
  counter = -2;
} else if (pagCount === 4) {
  counter = -3;
} else if (pagCount === 5) {
  counter = -4;
}
```

so that if the user clicks on either chevron, they will be in the correct position in the slides already.

Is there a way to make this dynamic? At the moment I need to know the number of slides (5 currently) and must update this manually as more slides are added.

EDIT: Joschi's comment below resolved this issue.

Comment: `counter = 1 - pagCount`

Comment: @Joschi...thank you :D couldn't have been simpler! Not sure how to mark your comment as resolved so I will update my question!

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan You can post your answer, explaining what you did to solve it, with a credit to Joschi and accept it (Unless they want to post it, and then you should accept theirs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joschi helped with resolving this, the solution was to replace my if statements with `counter = 1 - pagCount`;

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
counter = -(pagCount - 1)
```

So if `pagCount = 10`
then `-(pagCount - 1) = -9`